# get a primary key without inserting empty rows

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

so in my application, when the user clicks add on something I should create an **Entity A** to carry the values which the user provides, this **Entity A** have an autoincremented-primary-key, also along the way of constructing **Entity A** there're another Entities that carry the key of **Entity A** as a foreign key as well as part of their composite key.

so my problem is that room prevents me from creating the other entities without providing the key of **Entity A** in their constructor annotating it with `@NonNull` as it's part of their composite key and it can't null.

now I don't know how to approach this problem,

- was it a mistake from the beginning to work with my entities as custom classes along my application and I should separate entities from custom classes ? (though they would be having the same fields)
- whenever the user clicks the add option, should I just push/insert an empty entity/row/tuple to get an autogenerated key so I could create the entities along the way?

please tell me your thoughts about this as it's my first time to work with a database embedded in an application so I don't know what should regarding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this Entity A have an autoincremented-primary-key

`AUTOINCREMENT`, in Room `autoGenerate = true` as part of the `@PrimaryKey` annotation, does not actually result in auto generation. Rather it is a constraint rule that forces the next automatically generated rowid to be greater than any that exist or have existed (for that table).

Without AUTOINCREMENT if the column is INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (or implied via a table level definition of such a column as PRIMARY KEY) then the column is made an alias of the always existing rowid *(except for the rarely used WITHOUT ROWID table (unable to do so in Room via entities, there is no annotation for such a table))*.

The rowid is always unique and always automatically generated and will typically be greater (typically 1 greater) anyway. It is only (unless purposefully manipulated) when the max (9223372036854775807th rowid) is reached when AUTOINCREMENT comes into play. In which case with AUTOINCREMENT you get an SQLITE_FULL exception, without SQLITE will try to find a lower unused/free rowid.

- Due to the unnecessary overheads [see](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)  I personally never use autoGenerate = true.
- What AUTOINCREMENT does, is have a system table sqlite_sequence with a row per table that has AUTOINCREMENT where it stores/maintains the highest allocated rowid for the table. With AUTOINCREMENT it then uses the higher of the sqlite_sequence value and the highest rowid value and then adds 1 (without it just uses the highest rowid and adds 1).

> was it a mistake from the beginning to work with my entities as custom classes along my application and I should separate entities from custom classes ?

There should be no need to have separate classes an Entity can be used as a stand-alone class, the room annotations being ignored.

> whenever the user clicks the add option, should I just push/insert an empty entity/row/tuple to get an autogenerated key so I could create the entities along the way?

It is very easy to get the generated key and @Insert for a single insert returns the key (id) as a long so the @Dao `@Insert abstract fun(entityA: EntityA): Long (long in Java)` returns the key or -1 if the insert did not insert a row.

If you use the list/varargs for of @Insert then it returns a and array of Longs, each element returning the key (id) of the insert or -1.

So considering what I believe is your issue consider the following 3 Entities (not if Java then use Long rather than long for the key as primitives can't be null).

```
@Entity
data class EntityA(
    @PrimaryKey
    var entityAKey: Long? = null,
    var otherAdata: String
)
```

- No AUTOINCREMENT via autoGenerate = true.
- No @NOTNULL annotations

then :-

```
@Entity
data class EntityB(
    @PrimaryKey
    var entityBKey: Long?= null,
    var otherBdata: String
)
```

and :-

```
@Entity(
    primaryKeys = ["entityBRef","entityARef","otherPartOfPrimaryKey"]
)
data class EntityC(
    var entityBRef: Long,
    var entityARef: Long,
    var otherPartOfPrimaryKey: Long,
    var otherCData: String
)
```

add some Dao's :-

```
@Insert
abstract fun insert(entityA: EntityA): Long
@Insert
abstract fun insert(entityB: EntityB): Long
@Insert
abstract fun insert(entityC: EntityC): Long
```

- NOTE the Long return value (always Long doesn't compile if Int) and generated keys should always be long anyway as they can exceed what an Int can hold.

Finally consider :-

```
    db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
    dao = db.getDao()
    
    var myfirstA = EntityA(otherAdata = "First")
    var myfirstB = EntityB(otherBdata = "The first B")
    var a1 = dao.insert(myfirstA)
    var b1 = dao.insert(myfirstB)
    dao.insert(EntityC(b1,a1,100L,"The first C using id's from the first A and the first B"))
```

- run on the main thread via `allowMainThreadQueries()`

And the database :-

[image]

[image]

[image]

You could even do :-

```
    dao.insert(EntityC(
        dao.insert(EntityB(otherBdata = "Second B")), 
        dao.insert(EntityA(otherAdata = "A's second")), 
        200,
        "blah")
    )
```

- obviously this would likely be of limited use as you'd need to know the values up front.

And the result is :-

[image]

[image]

[image]

- Database snapshots obtained via Android studio's App Inspector (formerly Database Inspector).

You could also do/use :-

```
    var my3rdA = EntityA(otherAdata = "3rd")
    my3rdA.entityAKey = dao.insert(my3rdA)
```

Of course whenever you extract from the database then the object will include the key (id) (unless you purposefully chose not to).

Comment: never thought that I would get an answer that long thanks man, I guess changing Long to its primitive would solve my problem temporary, and whenever I insert the main entity and get the key value I will change the value in other entities